# Google Chart Tool Example Not Working

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am using the php post request example given on http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html for generating chart.

The code:
chartserver-image.php

```
<?php
 // Create some random text-encoded data for a line chart.
 header('content-type: image/png');
 $url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
 $chd = 't:';
 for ($i = 0; $i < 150; ++$i) {
 $data = rand(0, 100000);
 $chd .= $data . ',';
 }
 $chd = substr($chd, 0, -1);

// Add data, chart type, chart size, and scale to params.
$chart = array(
'cht' => 'lc',
'chs' => '600x200',
'chds' => '0,100000',
'chd' => $chd);

// Send the request, and print out the returned bytes.
$context = stream_context_create(
array('http' => array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($chart))));
fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
?>
```

another_page.html

```
<img width='600' height='200' src='chartserver-image.php'>
```

Right now when i access another_page.html, the image doesn't load when i click on view image it shows

The image “http://localhost/demo/chartserver-image.php” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

What is the issue i am unable to understand?

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing  'content' => http_build_query($chart)))); with 'content' => http_build_query($chart,'', '&')))); resolves the issue.

I have added arg separator '&' to  http_build_query() which avoid bug if the
arg_separator.output parameter is modified in php.ini.

When i checked phpinfo the arg_separator.output was &amp. That was causing issue so adding '&' to http_build_query() resolves the problem.

Comment: +1 that seems to have solved my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682622/anyone-having-problems-with-google-charts-in-xampp

Comment: oops, sorry, no it didn't  -something else did, sorry. But it's a good point to make anyway

Answer (score 1):

This will work Absolutely fine... Some mistakes in the above example i think.. they are solved below.

```
<?php

 // Create some random text-encoded data for a line chart.
 header('content-type: image/png');
 $url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
 $chd = 't:';
 for ($i = 0; $i < 150; ++$i) {
 $data = rand(0, 100000);
 $chd .= $data . ',';
 }
 $chd = substr($chd, 0, -1);

// Add data, chart type, chart size, and scale to params.
$chart = array(
'cht' => 'lc',
'chs' => '600x200',
'chds' => '0,100000',
'chd' => $chd);

$query = http_build_query($chart);

$fullurl = $url."?".$query;

$context = stream_context_create(

    array(
            'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                                "Content-length: 0",

            )
    )
);

$ret = fopen($fullurl, 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($ret);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php

 // Create some random text-encoded data for a line chart.
 //header('content-type: image/png');
 $url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
 $chd = 't:';
 for ($i = 0; $i < 150; ++$i) {
 $data = rand(0, 100000);
 $chd .= $data . ',';
 }
 $chd = substr($chd, 0, -1);

// Add data, chart type, chart size, and scale to params.
$chart = array(
'cht' => 'lc',
'chs' => '600x200',
'chds' => '0,100000',
'chd' => $chd);

$query = http_build_query($chart);

$fullurl = $url."?".$query;

$context = stream_context_create(

    array(
            'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                                "Content-length: 0",
                    'proxy' => 'tcp://X.X.X.X:XXXX'
            )
    )
);

$ret = fopen(fullurl, 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying can you please clarify the need for  'proxy' => 'tcp://X.X.X.X:XXXX'. What is the value should i pass to this variable? 

Right now i am getting this error

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\chartserver-image.php on line 33

Comment: Warning: fopen(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&amp;chs=600x200&amp;chds=0%2C100000&amp; in E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\chartserver-image.php on line 33

Warning: fpassthru(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\chartserver-image.php on line 34

Comment: I tested it behind a proxy so that's why I had to have the `proxy` set. I'm no expert in `PHP`, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the identical problem, and I split

```
$context = stream_context_create(
array('http' => array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($chart))));
```

into two statements:

```
$x = array('http' => array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($chart)));

$context = stream_context_create($x);
```

and that seemed to solve it (please don't ask me why)